# Is there way to show test author name in pytest-html reports for each tests?

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

Is there way to show test author name in pytest-html reports for each tests ?

Comment: What do you mean by author name? Are you referring  `__author__` attribute in test module?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can do that. Put `__author__` attribute in each test module.

```
# test_add.py

__author__ = 'Vivek R'


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def test_add():
    assert add(5, 4) == 9
```

And call some fixtures in `conftest.py` file.

```
# conftest.py

from py.xml import html
import pytest


def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.append(html.th("Author"))


def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.append(html.td(report.author))


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.author = item.module.__author__
```

[image]